# Active admin Place a form above the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, panel, activeadmin

I have an application using active admin. All I tried to achieve is , to show a form above the active admin table. When the form is submitted , a request is placed which will be displayed in the table below the form. What I tried is,

- Tried to render the form in a panel within index
- Tried to have 2 index, one with the table and the other with rendering the form

The problem I faced in the above two solutions is , when there are no records in the table , the form is also not shown . When the table has records, the form is displayed

Is there a way so that the form is shown even if there are no records in index table. or, other ways of showing the form above the table. I also tried to write custom index, but could not locate the exact documentation for that

Answer (score 0):

First off, to render a form you normally do:

```
form html: {:multipart => true} do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :content
      f.input :description
      f.input :price
      f.input :plan
      f.input :image, hint: f.project.image? ? image_tag(project.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "Upload JPG/PNG/GIF image")
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

inside the model. In my case it was projects.rb for project.rb

If you want to render a form via partial, simply do:

```
 # renders app/views/admin/posts/_some_partial.html.erb
    render 'some_partial', { post: post }
```

this will render any form into your admin panel.

If you want to insert an index:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Task do
  permit_params :title, :note, :video, :header, :tag, :project_id


  sortable tree: false, sorting_attribute: :tag

  index :as => :sortable do
    label :title
    actions
  end

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :header
    column :title
    column :tag
    column :project

    actions
  end
end
```

Comment: Where should I need to do the code `render 'some_partial', { post: post }` , in such way it gets displayed above the index

Comment: Please post your active_admin file where you want to render the form, otherwise it will be hard to tell.